# Using jquery and ajax to retrieve a set of image path

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am implementing an online book application. It is based on html.

Generally, the book is double page . However , only single page is shown for the first page and it is page 1. I need loading six page for each time. For instance, if user read the 4th 5th page , what I need to get are 2th 3th 4th 5th 6th 7th pages.

> So my idea is provide the folder name and one page number (i , e.g. i =
>   5th) and return i-3,i-2,i-1 ,i , i+1, i+2 image paths.

Here is some sample code I find:

```
public function getImage(){
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        //d($params);
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
        {
                $src = $params['image_path'];

                exit;
        }        
    }
```

It is useful? and How can I convert it to accept the folder name/ page number? Thank you

Comment: header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); is not needed your are only sending path not content type of image,there is a lot of plugin available

Comment: You will need to format that sample code to fit your specific needs. See the jquery api for ajax.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to read that doc and make a demo page , where i have  variables storing folder name and page number

Comment: By the way, then what is the different if I use javascript to change the img src = " Folder Name / PageNo.jpg" , what is the point of using ajax?